# OpenLDAP not reachable from Apache Dir Studio

Tags: ldap, openldap

I recently installed openldap on RHEL 7. Service is running and slaptest is find too. But when I try to connect using Apache Directory Studio, it fails.

```
[root@openldap.redhat ~]$ netstat -tulpn | grep slapd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2631/slapd
tcp6       0      0 :::389                  :::*                    LISTEN      2631/slapd
[root@openldap.redhat ~]$ slaptest -u
config file testing succeeded
[root@openldap.redhat ~]$ ps -eaf | grep ldap
ldap       2631      1  0 00:04 ?        00:00:00 slapd -u ldap -h ldapi:/// ldap:/// -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
root       2676   2595  0 00:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ldap
```

Authentication with directory manager is also successful

```
[root@openldap.redhat ~]$ ldapsearch -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=maxcrc,dc=com> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# maxcrc.com
dn: dc=maxcrc,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
dc: maxcrc

# People, maxcrc.com
dn: ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
ou: People
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# Group, maxcrc.com
dn: ou=Group,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
ou: Group
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 4
# numEntries: 3
```

Server is pingable from my machine
But, when i try same from Apache Dir Studio, **it fails**. **What could be an issue?**
[image]

Comment: I cannot tell from your post, but are you running Apache Directory Studio on a different machine than the one running OpenLDAP? If so, can you confirm that the OpenLDAP server allows connections on port 389 from the machine running ADS? If not, that could be your problem. To do this you can use any telnet client or `nc`.

Comment: @rlandster I sovled it... Yes, Apache Directory Studio is on different machine. It is on windows while the OpenLDAP is on RHEL. It was firewall on RHEL which was block the connection. I stopped it using `systemctl stop firewalld`